# How to validate html for WCAG in a Continuous Integration environment? (Jenkins)

Tags: php, html, validation, jenkins, wcag

we are using Jenkins for our CI.

Our code is mainly in PHP (Zend framework), and we would like to validate every commit to comply with WCAG standards.

Alternatively, we would like to validate the HTML using some customs rules (no IMG tag without ALT attribute, no HTML tag without lang, etc).

Does anyone know a good plugin that might be useful or have some lead to implement a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to code some checks yourself have a look at [HTML_CodeSniffer](http://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/) the [sources](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer) are on Github. 
You can call that via jenkins "Execute Shell" or in your build scripts.